# When printing my questions for my input values, two of them print together, how could i fix this?

Tags: c, printf

I need to ask for three values however when I try to print the question to ask for the values it prints them together

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
   char carModel; 
   int tankRange; 
   float gasCost; 
   float costTank; 

   printf("What is the model of car? " );
   scanf("%c\n", &carModel);
   printf("How many miles can be driven on a full tank? " );
   scanf("%d\n", &tankRange);
   printf("What is the gas cost per gallon? " );
   scanf("%f\n", &gasCost);

   return 0;
}
```

What I was hoping to have was a output asking first for the model, then after recieving that asking for the full tank range then lastly ask for cost of gas however what happens is, it firstly asks for the model however when it comes time to ask for the other two it just prints both at once. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `\n` from all `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove unused variable.
2. Minimize scope of variables.
3. Remove the trailing "\n" on your prompt otherwise `scanf()` will be looking for the next non-white space character which is not what you want.
4. Check the return value otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized values.
5. You probably also want charModel to be more than 1 character, and ensure we specify the maximum field width when reading a string with `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CARMODELLEN 20
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main(void) {
    printf("What is the model of car? " );
    char carModel[CARMODELLEN+1];
    if(scanf("%" str(CARMODELLEN) "s", &carModel) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("How many miles can be driven on a full tank? " );
    int tankRange;
    if(scanf("%d", &tankRange) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("What is the gas cost per gallon? " );
    float gasCost;
    if(scanf("%f", &gasCost) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
What is the model of car? fiat
How many miles can be driven on a full tank? 2
What is the gas cost per gallon? 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *carModel; 
    int tankRange; 
    float gasCost; 
    float costTank; 

    carModel = malloc(256);

    printf("What is the model of car? " );
    scanf("%255s", &carModel);  // Don't read more than 255 chars
    printf("How many miles can be driven on a full tank? " );
    scanf("%d", &tankRange);
    printf("What is the gas cost per gallon? " );
    scanf("%f", &gasCost);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
What is the model of car? fiat
How many miles can be driven on a full tank? 2
What is the gas cost per gallon? 1
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?